# Manipulation of date in Groovy language

Tags: groovy

I have this script in Groovy:

```
currentDate = new Date().format( 'yyyyMMdd' )
```

I want to be able to manipulate the date in order to 'play' with the dates of it..
for example if I have this:`20150701` I want to subtract days, weeks or months for example if I subtract one day it will be `20150630`.

How can I do it without using `TimeCategory`?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Without `TimeCategory`, you can only add or subtract days. If you want to add/subtract other fields, `TimeCategory` is a good way to go.

If your annoyance with `TimeCategory` is the `with` syntax, one alternative would be to use mixins (although they are generally considered deprecated since traits have been added to Groovy):

```
[Date, Integer].each { it.mixin(groovy.time.TimeCategory) }
def lastMonth = new Date() - 1.months
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I have the answer to it, I tried this and it worked:

```
currentDate = new Date()
def yesterday = currentDate - 1

currentDate = yesterday.format("yyyyMMdd")
```